# Automated backup of S3 to another cloud

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

Is there a service out there to auto backup our S3 account to a external cloud?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at Google Cloud Platform Cloud Storage. It includes a [Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/) that is able to do scheduled daily and/or one-time transfer of an S3 bucket to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

Google Cloud Storage also has a versioning capability but it is turned off by default. From what I can tell you have to [turn versioning on](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning) via command-line or API (there isn't a UI to control versioning). Also, it is not possible to look at or download different versions of a file via a Web UI.

Some negatives: (1) This isn't so much "BACKUP" as versioned replication. (2) The web UI doesn't appear to expose all of the functionality one might need. (3) What happens if the Transfer Service encounters a problem? For my purposes I was hoping to set this up and ignore it unless there were exceptions. It doesn't appear that an e-mail alert is built-in so someone either needs to periodically visit the status page or make use of the API in some manner.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything off the top of my head, but it's really trivially simple to do with the S3 API, and another cloud's API.  You'd probably need an intermediate server, unless the 3rd party has a HTTP Pull method.

I'd probably set up an EC2 micro instance running ubuntu, or something, and script a cronjob that copies new files to the other cloud. You could use `find` to find files which had been modified/created since the last cronjob run.

I'd probably do it in python with python-boto.  Seems to work quite well for that kind of S3 manipulation.

If your cloud provider has a HTTP Pull method, then you could just set the ACL on the S3 objects to allow authenticated HTTP access, and copy them over that way.